# How can I view an internal table in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm specifically looking for a way to view the full text index fragments and the xml index, which, [according to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879306.aspx#fragments), are stored as internal tables. [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366343%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) describes how to view the internal table metadata. What I'm hoping for is a way to view the data in the internal tables.

Comment: Heads up - removed "hack" tag since your intentions for using the data aren't relevant to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the schema name and table names from `sys.internal_tables`

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(name)
FROM sys.internal_tables
```

Then if you are connected [via the DAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189595.aspx) you can simply select from them

```
select * from [sys].[xml_index_nodes_1765581328_256000]
select * from [sys].[fulltext_avdl_1077578877]
select * from [sys].[ifts_comp_fragment_610101214_4]
```

There may well be better ways of getting whatever the information is that you want though. e.g. the DMVs related to full text indexing in SQL Server 2008 [are listed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174971%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Comment: thank you. the instructions worked great, and the [DMVs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174971%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) were an added bonus!